# Update only one of two UITextFields stored in userData in Swift 5.3

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, swift5, userdefaults

Using UserDefaults to store two user input fields to be used throughout various VCs.  UILabels show the current settings, while UITextFields accept updated input.  I can set, store, display and update the two fields, but updates have to be in tandem.  I cannot figure out the proper method to update only one of the two fields.  As an example, update the email only, without touching "evernote" in my case.  Without the work around below, and when only inputting one of two fields, the second non-input field is overridden as blank.

As a work around, I include the saved data as the initial input for the two UITextFields.  Code works, just does not seem to be optimal.  Ideally the two UITextFields would not have initial values.  I have mucked around with != null statements in the button function, but to no avail.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Class to share userData input among VCs:

class UDM {

```
static let shared = UDM()
let userData = UserDefaults(suiteName: "xxxx.saved.data")!
```

}

Outlets and Actions:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var evernoteLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var enterEmail: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var enterEvernote: UITextField?

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UDM.shared.userData.set(enterEmail?.text, forKey: "email")
    UDM.shared.userData.set(enterEvernote?.text, forKey: "evernote")
}
```

viewDidLoad UI:

```
    let emailObject = UDM.shared.userData.object(forKey: "email")
    if let email = emailObject as? String {
        enterEmail?.text = email
        emailLabel.text = email
    }
    
    let evernoteObject = UDM.shared.userData.object(forKey: "evernote")
    if let evernote = evernoteObject as? String {
        enterEvernote?.text = evernote
        evernoteLabel.text = evernote
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting in case someone else is as dumb as I am.  In the if/then statements for the UITextFields, I looked at enterEmail or enterEvernote as fields.  Once I realized you need to look at the .text in the fields, it all fell into place.  Updated action is pretty simple then:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if enterEmail?.text != "" {
        UDM.shared.userData.set(enterEmail?.text, forKey: "email")
    }
    if enterEvernote?.text != "" {
        UDM.shared.userData.set(enterEvernote?.text, forKey: "evernote")
    }
}
```